# Is 404 status code suitable for a non existent entity upon insertion?

Tags: rest, http, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

Assume that I need to insert a record in my DB which has a foreign key constraint to another entity for which the client supplies a non existent id.

Obviously I check for the existence of the mentioned foreign key. Should I return the `404` status code or is something like `422 - Unprocessable Entity` a more suitable response code?

Comment: this might answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727699/is-http-404-an-appropriate-response-for-a-put-operation-where-some-linked-resour

Comment: @codebrane thanks, but [here](https://httpstatuses.com/409) it says that `409` is most likely used in response to `PUT` requests. Isn't there a better code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing is to decide whether it's a server (5xx) or a client (4xx) error. You could argue that the server only does what the client tells it to do, so it's a client error but why is the client expecting the id to exist? Has the server caused a problem? Has an earlier error lead to the wrong HTTP status code being sent to the client when it tried to create the entity with the missing id? Can you catch such an error so you don't need to handle this situation as it may not exist?

The client isn't looking for something so I don't think 404 is a suitable response. If the client is going to insert then 404 should never occur as that's the original state of the resource the client has yet to create.

409 is for problems to do with the state of the resource but the problem is really about the state of another resource, which is missing. 409 requires information to be returned to allow the caller to resolve the conflict. Can the client create the missing id if it gets a 409 from the server?

428 looks like a candidate as the request is conditional on the existence of the missing id but it requires the response to contain info on how to resolve the problem.

It's really about how the server can tell the client how to fix the problem. If it can, pick the best 4xx code that lets the server do that. If it can't perhaps it needs to tell the client it's done something it shouldn't have and return a 5xx, allowing that resource (which may be important to the client) to be flagged and handled differently.

[HTTP REST code](http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html)

Comment: Potentially the situation can not happen since the system  does not send a non existent id to the user. This is just to be on the safe side, that being said, the sever can only tell the client that the supplied resource id does not exists, so technically the request could not be processed, hence the `422` status code?

Comment: 422 seems to be an old(ish) way of dealing with what is generally taken to be a webdav error. It's for an entity that can't be 'processed'. You could say the entity was processed, i.e. deserialized into the relevant object and processed correctly according to the policy at the server but some other policy caused the failure (missing foreign key). So the entity was correctly processed but the error was a missing resource. https://www.keycdn.com/support/422-unprocessable-entity/

Comment: the ultimate error appears to be a precondition that hasn't been met, the existence of the missing id, rather than fact that it's missing.

Comment: 412/428 is meant for ETag / If-Match.

Answer (score 4):

According with https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5, 404 is used in case:

- The request-uri was not match
- he server doesn't want to reveal why the request has been refused
- No other response is applicable

Therefore, I would use 422.