# HTTP Status code for PUT with mysql id.

Tags: http, http-status-codes

We have a PUT endpoint which updates a row with autoincremented MYSQL id. If we specify the id in the body of the request, as in change the id value, the endpoint does not change the id (which is right behavior). But it also returns 200 because technically no validation failed. Should this return a 200? Or should it be a 400 or 403?

Comment: Semantics that totally dosen't change a thing in my opinion. I would personally return 400. 403 is mostly about lack of permissions, not about wrong request.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are seeing and what you are intending. You send an ID to change something, but it doesn't change, and that's the right behaviour?

Comment: It changes given column of given id to given value, but you can send a request in which you can try to change the id column itself, that is denied. That's how I understand it. Error 400 means that client made something wrong, 403 that tried to do something without proper permissions, 200 that everything went ok. In my opinion the less an unauthorised person knows about what went wrong, the safer server is. Really depends of situation... what API is it, who uses it, how is it used etc.

Comment: The return value should reflect the outcome of the `PUT` operation. Do I understand correctly that your PUT operation was "successful"? Then 200 is the correct return code. Otherwise, if the operation is logically "failed", the corresponding error can be returned. See for example returning 404 in `PUT` if `id` not found: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727699/is-http-404-an-appropriate-response-for-a-put-operation-where-some-linked-resour

Comment: @FlashThunder - Our QA team was testing the flow in which they were trying to change the id column itself. The change did not happen which is good as we don't want to change the id of a row. But the API returns 200. Is that the right status code or should it be 400?

Comment: @Madhu I highly appreciate a feedback for my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51966911/1426227).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we specify the id in the body of the request, as in change the id value, the endpoint does not change the id (which is right behavior).

If the id received in the payload matches the id stored in the database and the update succeeds, the service should return a [successful status code](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3) such as [`204`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5) or [`200`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.1).

On the other hand, if the id received in the payload doesn't match the id stored in the database, I would understand that as a [client error](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.5). And [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) seems to be a *reasonable choice*: It's used to indicate that the request *conflicts* with the current state of the resource on the server. The *mismatch* between the id in the payload and in the database is a conflict.

See how the [`409`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8) status code is defined in the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.5.8.  409 Conflict**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.8)
>
> The `409` (Conflict) status code indicates that the request could not
> be completed due to a conflict with the current state of the target
> resource.  This code is used in situations where the user might be
> able to resolve the conflict and resubmit the request.  The server
> SHOULD generate a payload that includes enough information for a user
> to recognize the source of the conflict. [...]

The response should include all necessary information for the client to recognize the source of the conflict and then be able to resubmit the request. For reporting problems in a Web API, I advise you to check the [RFC 7807](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7807).